# setw not working as expected

Tags: c++, setw

I'm trying to print time in hh:mm format but when the time is like 01:01 it prints as 1:1. Here's my code:

```
void output(int hour, int min, char ampm){
    cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << "The time is: " << hour << ":" << min << " ";

    if(ampm == 'P'){
        cout << "PM";
    }
    else if (ampm == 'A'){
        cout << "AM";
    }
}
```

As I understand it, this **should** work. I include iomanip. Can you see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The width is a special formatting setting: While all other formatting flags are stick, the `width()` will be reset by each output operator (well, you can have user-defined output operators which don't reset the `width()` but doing so would not follow the normal style). That is, you need to set the width immediately prior to the output that should be affected:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('0')
          << std::setw(2) << hour << ':'
          << std::setw(2) << min << ' ';
```

Comment: how incredibly convenient, std::ostream. thank you for this answer, @Dietmar.

Answer (score 2):

Following is correct way:

```
 cout<<""The time is: ";
 cout << setfill('0') <<setw(2) << hour << ":" <<setw(2) << min << " ";
```

Ref :-[this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it had to be right before the variable.